Number of permutations when you are allowed to hold one element in pocket
Find the number of permutations of size $n$ which can be constructed by the following algorithm:

The algorithm starts with a pocket variable $x \leftarrow 0$ and an empty list $L$
It iterates over each integer $i$ in $I = [1, 2, \dots n]$:

If $x \not= 0$, then the algorithm can chose to release, i.e., append $x$ in $L$. If it does so, then the value of $x$ becomes $0$
If $x \not= 0$, then the algorithm must append $i$ in $L$
Otherwise if $x = 0$, then the algorithm can chose to hold the integer, i.e., make $x \leftarrow i$, and not append $i$ in $L$. If it choses not to, then it must append $i$ in $L$


Output $L$


Motivation
A modern game of tetris consists of a "7 bag" feature (which is a random piece generator for a game, more info here)  and a hold mechanic.
There are 7 different pieces, hence the 7 bag being all unique pieces randomized.
As for the hold mechanic, one can choose to move the active piece in play off to the side. then later swap it back.
The question I have is, for a given random draw of the 7 unique pieces, how many different permutations are there for the order in which these 7 pieces are ultimately released in the stack. And in general, how would this work for a game that has $n$ unique pieces?
For example, for a game with only 3 pieces a, b and c, there are 4 permutations possible: Without loss of generality, assume the random order of the pieces in the game is a, b and c. Given the rules for how the hold mechanic works, the the 4 different permutations of interest are:

a, b, c
hold(a), b, c, release(a)
hold(a), b, release(a), c
a, hold(b), c, release(b)


The answer for the general problem is $2^{n-1}$ number of permutations which can be output by the algorithm (or $2^6 = 64$ for teris with the 7-bag feature)
We will show this by creating another algorithm $\text{Algo}_2$ different from the one given in the problem, which I will label as $\text{Algo}_1$. $\text{Algo}_2$ is defined as :

The algorithm starts with a list $A = [1, 2, \dots, n]$ and an empty list $L$
For $n-1$ times, the algorithm can chose one of the first two elements in $A$, append it in $L$, and remove it from $A$ (while preserving the order of other elements)
Append the last remaining element in $A$ to $L$.
Output $L$

I argue that every permutation that can be  output by $\text{Algo}_1$ can also be output by $\text{Algo}_2$, and vice versa. This is by comparing the possible states and their transitions:

The state when $\text{Algo}_1$ has reached integer $i$ in iteration with $x=0$, is identical to the state in $\text{Algo}_2$ with remaining $A = [i, i+1, \dots, n]$

$\text{Algo}_1$ not holding $i$ is identical to $\text{Algo}_2$ picking $i$
$\text{Algo}_1$ holding $i$ leads directly to the below state for $i+1$ ( no step taken in $\text{Algo}_2$ yet)


The state when $\text{Algo}_1$ has reached integer $i$ in iteration with some $x\not=0$, is identical to the state in $\text{Algo}_2$ with remaining $A = [x, i, i+1, \dots, n]$

$\text{Algo}_1$ releasing $x$ is identical to $\text{Algo}_2$ picking $x$. This leads to the above state back again ( while $\text{Algo}_1$ is still iterating on $i$)
$\text{Algo}_1$ not releasing $x$ is identical to $\text{Algo}_2$ picking $i+1$



